# Filtering SqlDataSource based on user

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource

I'm retrieving data from my database which is easily done by assign the query to SelectCommand.  However I want display certain records based on the type of user that is logged in.  I'm using ASP.Net & C#.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceInbox" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnectionString %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 

    SelectCommand="SELECT MESSAGE_ID, FACILITY_ID, TYPE, DEPARTMENT, STATUS, REMARKS
                   FROM INBOX ORDER BY DATE_RECIEVED"
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I've attempted to use the code-behind by accessing the properties through it's ID but that doesn't seem to work.  Any ideas? or would it be better to handle it without code-behind?

Comment: how are you determining the user type?

Comment: I am determining user type by their facility id.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Sql Server and SqlClient Provider, you can construct you query as follow:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceInbox" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT MESSAGE_ID, FACILITY_ID, TYPE, DEPARTMENT, STATUS, REMARKS
                    FROM INBOX ORDER BY DATE_RECIEVED
                    WHERE USER_NAME=@UserName"
     runat="server">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

See that I´m adding a WHERE clause filtering by an hypothetical field "USER_NAME" (or other field you want) and a parameter @UserName.

So, in the code behind you get the logged user name and add the select parameter with its value:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string user = User.Identity.Name;
        SqlDataSourceInbox.SelectParameters.Clear();
        SqlDataSourceInbox.SelectParameters.Add("@UserName", user);
    }
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: This looks good along lines of what I was thinking but oddly in my code-behind file it doesn't recognize the ID="SqlDataSourceInbox".  Generally, I should have access to this in the code-behind right?  I might need to look at why isn't know seen.  I do appreciate the help.

Comment: The id of SqlDataSource MUST be accessible in the code behind as an instance variable. In this case, if you define <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceInbox" ... > is supposed to possible to access this instance variable. Try to add other controls to the page and access its properties in codebehind.